# How to select distinct the first column of a composite primary key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

So I have a table that keeps events organized into separate streams. Each stream has id (stream_id) and the events in a stream have a subsequent number (sequence_number). The events are strings (JSON).

```
mydb=# \d stream
                    Table "public.stream"
      Column       |          Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 stream_id         | character varying(255)  |           | not null | 
 sequence_number   | bigint                  |           | not null | 
 event             | character varying(2000) |           | not null | 

Indexes:
    "stream_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (stream_id, sequence_number)
```

For testing purposes I have inserted 5 000 000 records into this table.

In order to find all unique stream_id-s I use select distinct on the first column of the composite primary key and it takes 18 seconds:

```
mydb=# select distinct stream_id from stream;
 stream_id 
-------------------
 site-6
 site-1
 site-3
 site-9
 site-7
 site-2
 site-0
 site-5
 site-8
 site-4
 site-x
(11 rows)

Time: 18070.055 ms (00:18.070)
```

In the same time if I do that manually I can do it under a second (note that the unique values of the first column are a very small number compared to the total row count):

1. first find the smallest one:

```
mydb=# select min(stream_id) from stream;
  min
--------
 site-0
(1 row)

Time: 31.231 ms
```

2. then find the next bigger one then the last one and again and again...:

```
mydb=# select stream_id from stream where stream_id>'site-0' order by stream_id limit 1;
 stream_id 
-------------------
 site-1
(1 row)

Time: 22.506 ms
```

```
mydb=# select stream_id from stream where stream_id>'site-1' order by stream_id limit 1;
 stream_id 
-------------------
 site-2
(1 row)

Time: 30.054 ms
```

```
mydb=# select stream_id from stream where stream_id>'site-2' order by stream_id limit 1;
 stream_id 
-------------------
 site-3
(1 row)

Time: 15.362 ms
```

```
mydb=# select stream_id from stream where stream_id>'site-3' order by stream_id limit 1;
 stream_id 
-------------------
 site-4
(1 row)
...
```

So the question is if there is a way to optimize the select distinct query somehow instead of manually traversing the primary key index with multiple selects?

EDIT1: Note that this single table is optimized for adding/fetching events to/from the streams in a sequential way and the performance of these exact operations is the most important one.

Comment: `select distinct` is as optimized as it gets.

Comment: @GMB not sure what do you mean but I have actually proved that it is not well optimized because using manual selects I can "implement" it in a far performant way!

Answer (score 0):

Could split up the data so retrieving the StreamId's doesn't also pull in the JSON documents. For example three tables:

1. Unique ID 1 + StreamId
2. Unique ID 2 + JSONDocument
3. Unique ID 1 + Unique ID 2 + Sequence Number : mapping table between them

More effort to work with but won't pull in the JSON document data when you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see how this is better then the manual procedure of finding all unique stream_id-s? As with it I can also keep the good ralational design (single table without any surrogate keys) optimized for adding/fetching events to/from streams which is the most important one (sorry, I have not mentioned that in the original post).